# Передать значение input radio в другой input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется каталог товаров.

У каждого товара есть варианты выбора в виде input type="radio".

Также у каждого товара есть кнопка "заказать" по нажатию на которую появляется форма обратной связи содержащая скрытый инпут.

Форма обратной связи вызывается для всех товаров одна и та же.

ID и label для инпутов генерируются скриптом

```
<script>
        $(function getValue() {
            $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(indx, el){
                $(this).next().attr("for" , "radio"+indx)
                this.id = "radio"+indx
                var id = "radio"+indx

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Каким образом можно передать value radio в другой input ?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. На него можно дать только самый общий ответ (в jQuery можно получить value с помощью ``$('#id1').val()`` и установить его с помощью ``$('#id2').val($('#id1').val())``). Чтобы сказать что-то более конкретное, нужно знать, как происходит обработка кнопки «заказать» и как реализован показ формы обратной связи. Укажите больше данных, желательно с кодом.

Comment: @Дмитрий Кушнарёв, показ формы реализован у меня через css (display:none) . Кнопка "заказать" осуществляет только показ формы. Инпуты у меня генерируются скриптом <script>
        $(function getValue() {
            $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(indx, el){
                $(this).next().attr("for" , "radio"+indx)
                this.id = "radio"+indx
                var id = "radio"+indx
            });
        });
    </script>